# rm -rf left an undeleteable directory; how can I remove it?

Tags: command-line, corruption, delete, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just `rm -rf`d some trash (long story short, don't use Unreal and Git, it breaks things). Now I have a file that `ls -Al` on Bash lists like this:

```
d????????? ? ?    ?    ?           ? old-folder-name
```

Its inode is listed as `?` by `ls -i`. `rm old-folder-name` fails with no such file or directory, and `ls` prints that message as well, though it doesn't stop it from actually listing it. Any attempts to `mv`, `cd` or the like fail for that reason, too.

I'm currently on WSL, and when deleting it through File Explorer on an administrator account, I get a nonsensical error about needing permission from an administrator. Both `del` and `rmdir` fail, too. Clearly, Windows won't work on this, either.

How can I delete this folder?

**NB:** After a reboot (that is, shutting it down for the night and reopening it in the morning) it's gone. I'd still like an explanation for how this kind of thing can happen.

Comment: As a side note, no idea how to tag this, in part because it's 0400 and in part because I'm new here. If I'm missing any info... well, hopefully it's still there after a reboot. I really want to figure out what's causing this, even though it's a pain in the butt. I've tagged [tag:corruption] because I'm fairly sure that's what this is, but... it's 0400. I've been awake a long time. I don't really trust myself right now.

Comment: Make sure you run a filesystem check on the drive. This might be caused by a bad sector

Answer (score 0):

The "file" you want to erase is not a file, it is a directory.
The simple command `rm` will not erase it, you need to use `rmdir` or a more complex rm command (like the rm -rf you used). Note also that rmdir will not erase the directory if it is not empty.

However, as ls is printing `?`'s it is probable that in the **parent** directory, the directory has read (r) but not execute (x) (cd into it) permissions.
The solution is to make the (parent) directory have x permissions, and if you are the owner, read and write permissions:

```
chmod 711 old-folder-name(parent)
```

Then, either (if old-folder-name is empty):

```
$ cd old-folder-name(parent)
$ rmdir old-folder-name
```

or:

```
$ cd old-folder-name\(parent\)/
$ rm -rf old-folder-name
```